# How to insert a image in payment page (offer banner)?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i want to insert offer banner in the payment page.

For reference please find the attached image and url

https://vitalticks.in/checkout/#payment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to onepage.phtml file in below path

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates

and add the image like this

getViewFileUrl('images/razorpay-disc.png'); ?>" />